# Программа разбор введенной строки по алфавиту. Неработает

Tags: c

Пишу программу которая будет введённый строку слов разбирать по словам и выстраивать в порядке алфавитных букв.

Вот код :

```
/* считываем строку и расставляем слова
   в общем считываю строку и растравляю слова
   1. считать строку
   2. разбить на слова
   3. растравить слова в порядке русского алфавита
   4. вывести слова
*/

#define _GNU_SOURCE

 //пример использования функции fputc
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     //strtod
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>  // pow

#include <string.h> // новое  

int main()
{
    // - безразмерная инициализация
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    printf("Введите строку :");
    getline(&line, &len, stdin);
    printf("Введёная строка :%s",line);

    // ввод
    char massiw[256][256];

    // фильтрация
    char alfavit_big[] = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    char alfavit_lit[] = "абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";

    // пузырьковsй алгоритм
    int t[256];
    // массив такой проходим весь массив и индексируем его
    // индексируем массив
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(massiw[256]); i++){
        for(int i1 =0; i1 < 32; i1++){
            if(massiw[i][0] == alfavit_big[i1])
                t[i] = i1;
            if(massiw[i][0] == alfavit_lit[i1])
                t[i] = i1;
        }
    }

// выводим растравляем массив в соответствии алфавиту :3
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 256 - i - 1; j++) {
            if(t[j] > t[j+1]) {
                // тут массив слов
                char *tmp = *massiw[j];
                *massiw[j] = *massiw[j+1];
                *massiw[j+1] = *tmp;
                // а тут массив чисел
                char tmp1 = t[j];
                t[j] = t[j+1];
                t[j+1] = tmp1;
            }
        }
    }

// вывод уже отфильтрованной строки
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 256; j++){
       printf("%s",massiw[i][j]);
   }
   printf(" ");
}
printf("\n");


    //  конец программы очистка буферов
    free(line);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Вот результат с учётом ответа  AlexGlebe :

```
/* считываем строку и расставляем слова
   в общем считываю строку и растравляю слова
   1. считать строку
   2. разбить на слова
   3. растравить слова в порядке русского алфавита
   4. вывести слова
*/

#define _GNU_SOURCE

//пример использования функции fputc
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     //strtod
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>  // pow

#include <string.h> // новое


typedef struct {
    char s  [ 256 ] ;
} strin ;

void get_strings(char const *in)
{
    char *cmd;
    asprintf(&cmd, "string%s", in);
    if(system(cmd))
        fprintf(stderr, "что-то не так с запуском%s.\n", cmd);
    free(cmd);
}

int main()
{
    // - безразмерная инициализация
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    printf("Введите строку :");
    getline(&line, &len, stdin);
    printf("Введённая строка :%s",line);

    // ввод
    strin massiw  [ 256 ] ;

    // фильтрация
    char alfavit_big[] = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    char alfavit_lit[] = "абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";

    // пузырьковsй алгоритм
    int t[256];
    // массив такой проходим весь массив и индексируем его
    // индексируем массив
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        for(int i1 =0; i1 < 32; i1++){
            if(massiw[i].s[0] == alfavit_big[i1])
                t[i] = i1;
            if(massiw[i].s[0] == alfavit_lit[i1])
                t[i] = i1;
        }
    }

    // выводим растравляем массив в соответствии алфавиту :3
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 256 - i - 1; j++) {
            if(t[j] > t[j+1]) {
                // тут массив слов
                //                    char *tmp = *massiw[j];
                //                    *massiw[j] = *massiw[j+1];
                //                    *massiw[j+1] = *tmp;
                strin tmp = massiw[j];
                massiw[j] = massiw[j+1];
                massiw[j+1] = tmp;
                // а тут массив чисел
                char tmp1 = t[j];
                t[j] = t[j+1];
                t[j+1] = tmp1;
            }
        }
    }

    // вывод уже отфильтрованной строки

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        printf("%s", massiw[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //  конец программы очистка буферов
    free(line);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

вот вывод :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

//пример использования функции fputc
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     //strtod
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>  // pow

#include <string.h> // новое


typedef struct {
    char s [256];
} strin ;

void get_strings(char const *in)
{
    char *cmd;
    asprintf(&cmd, "string%s", in);
    if(system(cmd))
        fprintf(stderr, "что-то не так с запуском%s.\n", cmd);
    free(cmd);
}

int main()
{
    // - реализация с размерами
    char line[256];    // сюда вводим строку

    printf("Введите строку :");gets(line);
    printf("Введёная строка :");puts(line);printf("\n");

    // ввод
    strin massiw [256];
    printf("1ю1\n");

    // разбиение строки на слова
    int i_t =0;
    for(int i = 0; line[i] != '\n'; i++){
        if(line[i] == ' ')
            i_t = i_t+1;
        massiw[i_t].s[i] = line[i];
    }
    printf("1ю2\n");

    printf("%s", line);

    printf("2ю1\n");

    // фильтрация
    char alfavit_big[] = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    char alfavit_lit[] = "абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";

    // пузырьковой алгоритм
    int t[256];

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        for(int i1 =0; i1 < 32; i1++){
            if(massiw[i].s[0] == alfavit_big[i1])
                t[i] = i1;
            if(massiw[i].s[0] == alfavit_lit[i1])
                t[i] = i1;
        }
    }

    // выводим растравляем массив в соответствии алфавиту :3
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 256 - i - 1; j++) {
            if(t[j] > t[j+1]) {
                // тут массив слов
                strin tmp = massiw[j];
                massiw[j] = massiw[j+1];
                massiw[j+1] = tmp;
                // а тут массив чисел
                char tmp1 = t[j];
                t[j] = t[j+1];
                t[j+1] = tmp1;
            }
        }
    }

    // вывод уже отфильтрованной строки
    printf("%s", massiw );

    //  конец программы очитка буферров
    free(line);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Вот вывод увы почему-то не выходит, растравить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Учить матчасть - учебники. Что массивы просто так, присваиванием не копируются. Смотреть в сторону функций `strcpy`, `memcpy`. У вас непонятно, что используется - вроде бы и не строки - нет никаких нулевых символов. И еще - что вы ожидаете от `sizeof(massiw[256])`? И зачем вы читаете строку, если с ней никак не работаете?

Answer (score 2):

В стандарте присваивания массивов нет, но существует присваивание структур. Это лечится так:

```
typedef struct {
  char s  [ 256 ] ;
} strin ;

    // ввод
    //char massiw[256][256];
    strin massiw  [ 256 ] ;
...
        for(int i1 =0; i1 < 32; i1++){
            if(massiw[i].s[0] == alfavit_big[i1])
                t[i] = i1;
            if(massiw[i].s[0] == alfavit_lit[i1])
                t[i] = i1;
...
                    // тут массив слов
                    strin tmp = massiw[j];
                    massiw[j] = massiw[j+1];  
                    massiw[j+1] = tmp;
```

Comment: `Введите строку :Приём Умной Работы`
`Введёная строка :Приём Умной Работы`
`(null)`
`Для закрытия данного окна нажмите <ВВОД>...`  Какой-то вывод печальный :(

Comment: добавил этот код чёто не запустилось :( вот вывод : `Введите строку :Раз Два
Введёная строка :Раз Два
(null)
Для закрытия данного окна нажмите <ВВОД>...`

Comment: У вас ещё писать и писать... Выставлять конец строки надо. Присваивание строки я вам сделал и всё.

Comment: обновил вопрос :3

Comment: Вам уже сказали, что `line` (введённую строку) вы вообще не используете.

Comment: @timob256 Это не форум. Задавайте другие вопросы как новые.

Comment: Мне ответ нужен, а не новые вопросы.